# socialengine v4 how to change the page members see after login

Tags: socialengine

I have been trying to do this for days now and cant seem to find any help on how to do is.  I want the user after login to be redirected to a different page instead of the members landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the code in `User/AuthController` after this comment `Run post login hook`. There are several ways to do a custom redirect here.

1. specify a `return_url` parameter in the link to login page. You can also 64-bit encode the redirect url so that it is compact.
2. Keep a session variable, namely `Zend_Session_Namespace('Redirect')->uri`
3. Write a post login hook `onUserLoginAfter` and pass a `redirect` parameter in its response.

If all else fails, hard-code the next line of code which redirects to home :P

Comment: "You can send a URL parameter to Login page" where do you do this with out changing code ?